# System.out in parameter

Tags: java

I have a test file and according to it I need to build my program the test file
is below. However, I confused by s1.showDetails(System.out); I have never met
System.out in parameter can anyone help. What to do with it??? when I am trying to write showDetails() the compiler writes mistake. my student code is beneath this Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Q2 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // Start on section A
        System.out.println("Question 2");
        System.out.println("Start on part A");
        Student s1 = new Student("John", "Smith", 42);
        s1.showDetails(System.out);
        Course cs = new Course("Computer science");
    }
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private int moduleMark;
    private int total;
    protected Student(String name, String familyName, int moduleMark)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.moduleMark = moduleMark;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getFamilyName()
    {
        return familyName;
    }

    public int getModuleMark()
    {
        return moduleMark;
    }

    public String showDetails()
    {
        return (this.name + " " + this.familyName + " " + moduleMark + total);
        //print(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the error you are getting. Also, if this is homework then add the 'homework' tag

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method showDetails() in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (PrintStream)

 at Q2.main(Q2.java:9)

Comment: Did you read the error message?  This code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your class "Student" don't have a method showDetails() with a parameter (PrintStream) in this case. So you can't call that in your main() block.

Comment: Of course I did but I cannot change test method I can only change my method but I don't know how to change that and in the internet I cannot find anything similar to that. I am new to programming and have not met System.out in parameter

Comment: "Your class "Student" don't have a method with a parameter in this case. So you can't call that in your main() block" Yeah, I understand that but I don't know what to put in a parameter I tried to put PrintStream, System.out and other classes but the error is appeared again and again

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Just to show it? Then return a String, and call it by System.out.println(). is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much describes what the problem is.

> The method showDetails() in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (PrintStream) at Q2.main(Q2.java:9)

The program tries to call your method with System.out which happens to be a PrintStream. So, change your showDetails to

```
public String showDetails(PrintStream out) {
    out.println(this.name + " " + this.familyName + " " + moduleMark + total);
}
```

This allows the tester (I assume there is a program which tests your assignment for correctness) to give you any PrintStream, either System.out or any other PrintStream.

Answer (score 6):

`System.out` is a variable like every other variable.

[System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a class

[out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a `public` `static` variable inside `System` of type `PrintStream`. So you can access it with `System.out`

So `System.out.println(..)` is just a call to the `println(..)` function of a `PrintStream`

So your function should look like:

```
public String showDetails(PrintStream stream) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error essentially means that the compiler didn't find the method with the name *showDetails* that takes an argument of type `PrintStream`. You have no need to pass the `System.out` to the `showDetails()` method. The correct way writing the `showDetails()` is below. Read about [System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).

```
public void showDetails()
{
   System.out.println(this.name + " " + this.familyName + " " + moduleMark + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program can't compile.

Your main is using a method named showDetails that takes a  PrintStream  as a parameter (System.out). And you are defining only a method named showDetails without parameter.

Look at the [doc of System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out). It s a field like any other of the class System. Indeed it's somewhat special as it is static but that doesn't change the game that much...

So write a method with the correct parameter list and you will get closer.

```
public String showDetails(PrintStream stream) {
 //your code here
}
```

showDetails should write to the stream passed in parameter.

While you are at learning programming. Try [to separate query from command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation). It's a good principle : a method should do one thing : either do something to your current object using a parameter or answer a query about the state of your current object. Not both. 
Here you return a string and require a stream... You should better split that into 2 methods : one to get the string and then as second one to call stream.write on that string.

```
public String toString() {
 //your code here
}

public void showDetails(PrintStream stream) {
 //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `print` is commented out from your `showDetails` message there are 2 obvious solutions

1. The `showDetails` message is not meant to print out anything (despite the name) and you should just print it out in the main method

   ```
   System.out.println( s1.showDetails() );
   ```
2. The `showDetails` message should print the String to any `PrintStream`, and then you have to adjust both the signature of that method as well as the implementation

   ```
   public String showDetails(PrintStream stream) {
     stream.println( ... );
   }
   ```